# Couldn't hear AVAudioRecorder's voice without headphones

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am recording voice on iPhone using AVAudioRecorder and these are my recorder settings:

```
 NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
```

The problem is that I can't hear the recorded voice without headphones.
I want to be able to hear the voice without headphones also.
How should I change my code?

Comment: have you checked for other audio files? means does other files getting played properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe force-routing the audio output to the speaker will help?

```
- (void) forceRouteAudioToSpeaker
{
    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
        sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);
}
```

Don’t forget to include `<AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>`. On second thought, switching the audio category to plain playback should also do the trick, and you say it didn’t…

Comment: Yes,you are right switching the audio category to plain playback does the trick

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the AVAudiosession category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` before playing the sound

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider is that if you do not set up your AVAudioSession for playback, then the silence ringer switch on the side of the phone will make your audio not play over the speaker.  In order for you to be able to play sound with a silenced phone make sure you are using something like this before triggering your AVAudioPlayer to play the file:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];
```